# Camel file camelLock blocks execution

Tags: apache-camel

I have a project where for example I have a simple route where files are taken from a directory and sent to ActiveMQ queue, but once I start the application some files get transferred and then the application stops before finishing to transfer all files. When checking the source folder a file with a .camelLock extension appears and nothing else continues. Anyone knows a solution to this problem ?

The route looks like:

```
<route trace="true">
    <from uri="file:src/testData"/>
    <to uri="jms:queue:input"/>
</route>
```

Comment: Does it create a .camel directory? If so what is in it? Presumably you're aware that any files starting with a dot won't be consumed?

Comment: @Sebastian I am also facing same problem. Did you slove this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If any exception occurs when processing the file , the file will not be moved to .camel or processed folder.So please add exception section and see what is happening in the route.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the file input stream might not be closed properly, that's why the file got locked(.camelLock). Close the file InputStream properly or Cross-check the code from Camel inputendpoint side and try to replace it with other proper alternative solution.

***Alternative Solution:***

In case,if you are unable to find open streams in your code, then apply below parameters to Apache camel route. The performance would be better.

```
readLockCheckInterval=1&amp;readLockTimeout=3
```

In my case Performance much better in windows.